# In Bayesian simulation, why use fixed value for the parameters, which has a prior, in the model?

Tags: simulation, bayesian

When simulating a Bayesian model, are we supposed to treat the parameters as a random variable (a prior), but not use a fixed value?

For example, we have a Bayesian linear model y=x\beta+\epsilon. When simulating it, literature usually: 1. set regression coefficients at fixed values, e.g. (0,3,-2,1,0,...); 2. simulate the predictors many times; 3. simulate the error term, usually standard normal; 4. generate the response.

If the regression coefficients have a prior (assume they have exchangeable priors), and thus we have posterior distributions, why would we simulate only one set of regression coefficients values? This sounds like the posterior has a distribution, meaning that we don't believe in any fixed value, while the truth indeed is fixed value. Even the posterior mean is supposed to converge to the OLS estimate under good setups, but this still feels difficult to understand.

Comment: Nothing wrong with looking at both. Fixing hyperparameters allows for generating model-typical datasets; sampling over hyperparameters yields a sample from the prior predictive distribution. The former can be helpful to probe identifiability of parameters of interest; the latter is useful to verify the appropriateness of dataset to the model space. Maybe clarify what the aim is.

Comment: Hi @merv, thanks a lot for your reply. My major confusion is if we believe the model is Bayesian, then the regression coefficients are RVs. Then we are not supposed to simulate a single fixed value. We should have simulated many times until the sample is good enough to represent the prior population. In addition, for each of such sample values, we can  also generate model-typical datasets, right?